# Entity Framework Core : model schema one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, schema

I am used to building a database and accessing data through tables, views, and stored procedures. In this case I have to build the database using Entity Framework Core migrations.

My database schema should look something like this:

```
Event
    Guid            Id
    varchar(50)     Name
    Guid            ContactId 
    varchar(1500)   Description

Contact
    Guid            Id
    varchar(20)     GivenName
    varchar(20)     SirName
    varchar(128)    EMail
    varchar(12)     Phone

Registration
    Guid            Id
    Guid            ContactId
    Guid            EventId

Credit
    Guid            Id
    Guid            ContactId
    Guid            EventId
    DateTime        Timestamp
    int             Score
```

`Contact` should have a one to many relationship to `Registration` and `Credit` tables. I would usually create a view linking the tables and query the view. The registration table should have a unique constraint for `ContactId` and `EventId` (1 registration per contact per event); however, the credit table should have a unique constraint that includes `ContactId`, `EventId`, and `Timestamp`.

I don't know how to build the class models and I have not figured out how to word a search to find what I'm looking for.

This is targeting .NET Core 7.0 using Entity Framework Core 7.0.7

Comment: Start from classes and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)

Comment: How to design a one to many relationship is ef core basics you can find in the docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many

Comment: Why not use Database Model first?

Comment: The documentation examples generate a different schema than I am looking for - I spent  all last week trying to figure out how to generate the classes to generate the schema using the documentation without any luck.  ICollection<classname> generates table schema with additional fields.

I would LOVE to use the database model first.  I tried to create the models from the database, then deleted the database and tried to regenerate the database but it generates different schema for the tables.